# Where/How Can Spam False Positives Be Reported To MessageLabs?

Tags: email, smtp, spam-filter, spam

An email I sent got flagged as spam by MessageLabs on the recipient side.  I'd like to proactively engage MessageLabs to tell me more about why this got quarantined (or at least fix it).

Is there an email address I can write to? Perhaps support portal I can reference? Or will they only work with their customers?

-M

Comment: Try checking the SMTP response (typically found in the mail log) and see if there's a reason and/or URL to view their policies. Also check the headers of the email in the quarantine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Send a message to support@messagelabs.com, you should include the email address of your recipient, maybe they will work with you, don't know. It will probably help them if you include the complete original message, (extract the .eml file and zip it)